# How to reduce this equation?

Tags: equations, amsmath, overleaf

I am dealing with following two equations:

```
$
\begin{equation}
f_{\gamma_m}(x)= 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{A\sigma^2_{h}}\text{exp}\left({-x/A\sigma^2_{h}}\right), B_m=0\\
\frac{2}{A\alpha^2 \sigma^2_{g_m}\sigma^2_{f_m}}K_0\left(2\sqrt{\frac{x}{A\alpha^2 \sigma^2_{g_m}\sigma^2_{f_m}}}\right), B_m=1\end{cases}
\end{equation}$
```

My query is , how can I generalize these two equation in to single equation.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a problem with the code or a math problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The equation typesets well. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Incidentally, shouldn't it be `-x/(A\sigma^2_{h})` rather than `-x/A\sigma^2_{h}` in the first row?

Answer (score 2):

I share the predicament of the other commentators, in that I don't know what you mean when you ask "how can I generalize these two equation in to [a] single equation?"

At any rate, I think you could make the equation at hand look much better by switching to display-style math, replacing the `\frac` expression in row 2 with an inline-style fraction (as you already do, by the way, in row 1), and take various measures to "snug up" the first- and second-level subscript terms to the material to their immediate left.

Here's a before-and-after comparison:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{Before}
\begin{equation}
f_{\gamma_m}(x)= 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{A\sigma^2_{h}}\text{exp}\left({-x/A\sigma^2_{h}}\right), B_m=0\\
\frac{2}{A\alpha^2 \sigma^2_{g_m}\sigma^2_{f_m}}K_0\left(2\sqrt{\frac{x}{A\alpha^2 \sigma^2_{g_m}\sigma^2_{f_m}}}\right), B_m=1\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\bigskip
\textcolor{red}{After}
\begin{equation}
f_{\!\gamma_{\mkern-1.5mu m}}(x)= 
\begin{dcases}
\frac{1}{A\sigma^2_{\!h}}\exp\bigl(
-x/(A\sigma^2_{\!h})\bigr), & B_m=0\\
\frac{2}{A\alpha^2 \sigma^2_{\mkern-4.5mu g_m}\sigma^2_{\mkern-5mu f_{\!m}}}K_0\Bigl(
2\sqrt{x/(A\alpha^2 \sigma^2_{\mkern-4.5mu g_m}\sigma^2_{\mkern-5mu f_{\!m}})}\,\Bigr), & B_m=1
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```